# Animation in Youtube Application for Android Tablets

Tags: android-layout, android-animation, android-gallery, android

Here is the screen shot of Youtube Application that we see in tablets.

[image: Youtube Screenshot]

I like this animation very much and want to try it in my application. So, I want to know about it. Can anyone tell me about it. What this animation is called and where I can find some knowledge and guide/tutorial for this?

Secondly what control is used in here? I have few things in my mind e.g. Gallery, GridView etc. Kindly share your knowledge.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YouTube uses a custom component we call the "carousel," written in Renderscript.